# Math required to solve Fourier Transform for periodic functions?

Tags: signal-processing

In my Signals & Systems course my professor said that although it's possible to solve the standard Fourier transform for periodic signals, it requires advanced math beyond what we've learned, so we instead solve for the Fourier coefficients and then use the periodic version of the equation to get the frequency response. I've taken up to differential equations and asked him if that was enough math to solve these types of integrals and he said no. So my question is, what type of math is actually required to solve these integrals? What advanced math courses/topics would he be referring to?

Comment: It is all about [generalized functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function), like [$\delta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: I know that it has to do with the Dirac delta function, but that's all I know. I'm wondering what particular branches of mathematics and specifically which math courses would teach you how to solve these problems.